# How to make DialogFragment show on android home screen?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

The hosting blank activity is shown behind the dialog, but I want it to be shown on top of the home screen. Is there a way to "hide" the activity since nothing is shown inside of it anyway? The activity is needed because I am planning on showing another dialog after the user clicks a selection from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! For anyone wondering, the answer is to make the activity transparent. Here's another stack overflow question that describes how: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android)